# BluetoothGattCallback callback method onCharacteristicChanged keeps triggering even if I kill my app

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I have a BLE android application and as usual I am using `BluetoothGattCallback` to receive data from BLE device periodically. However, even if I kill my application,`onCharacteristicChanged` method of `BluetoothGattCallback` keeps triggering and Android studio shows that **app is still running.**

I want that **all app processes should be killed** and `onCharacteristicChanged` should not be triggered after that.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is still running then per definition it is not killed. Usually you never destroy an app process, but let the system do so when you have no running components anymore. To correctly shut down your Bluetooth connections when you are done, call `close()` on the BluetoothGatt objects you have. When you are "done" is up to you, but for example in an Activity's `onDestroy` if the connection is "bound" to an Activity.

Comment: I have noticed that sometimes gatt.close() doesn't work as expected/answered by you. Any other way to properly close the connection?

Comment: Are you sure you close the correct BluetoothGatt objects and that you don't have any dangling ones? Otherwise it's a bug in your Android device.